# Running AWS XRay deamon on a lambda running docker container

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-xray

I am running a lambda function with docker for a .NET application. in fact I have two lambdas, one based on a docker image and the other one is packaged as a zip. while configuring Xray with both functions, the one that is Zip packaged works fine and being traced normally, but the lambda running based on a docker image does not send any traffic to Xray.
I have concluded now that I should run the XRay Deamon on the same container where my app is running, is that correct ? I have so far not found any documentation or example for this setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution. the xray daemon runs by default inside the lambda container as well. but if you run lambda inside a stepfunction in a distributed mode, no data will be sent according to AWS documentation. This was a very special use case where it does not matter if the daemon is running or not, lambda container will simply not be emitting any tracing information to the xray API.
I am considering now either running the lambda with stepfunctions in another mode (inline mode), or simply use another librariy (from the opentelemetry)